# Swift errors: 'manager()' is unavailable: use object construction 'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()'

Tags: objective-c, swift, afhttprequestoperation

I have this swift code that I think should work but it can't handle objective c static fields. I have tried to add "()" multiple places but nothing works.

```
func AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerDispatchOnMainQueue(mainQueue: Bool) -> AFHTTPRequestOperationManager {
    var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.manager
    manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer(readingOptions: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(readingOptions: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
    if (!mainQueue) {
        manager.completionQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    }
    return manager;
}
```

The field and properties looks like this:

```
+ (instancetype)manager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPRequestSerializer <AFURLRequestSerialization> * requestSerializer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPResponseSerializer <AFURLResponseSerialization> * responseSerializer;
```

I get those error messages:

> Error: 'manager()' is unavailable: use object construction
>   'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()' 
> Error: '() ->
>   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager!' does not have a member named
>   'responseSerializer' 
> Error: '() -> AFHTTPRequestOperationManager!'
>   does not have a member named 'requestSerializer' 
> Error: '() ->
>   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager!' does not have a member named
>   'completionQueue' 
> Error: function produces expected type
>   'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager!'; did you mean to call it with '()'?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that it should be `var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When Objective-C is imported into Swift, as you're doing with AFNetworking here, identifiable factory methods are converted to simple initializers.  In this case that means that (as @Martin points out) you should be using that form instead:

```
var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
```

Comment: Can you please help me with following question ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27999703/1030951